Unit-testing vanilla JS with hard-coded dependencies
Imagine I have a legacy JS app with code like this:
var thing = new Thing();
function do_thing() {
  // Logic to test here
}
// export module

This file also includes a number of important calculations I need to unit-test, without refactoring the whole thing.
I tried to test it with jest.
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
const mod = require('thing.js');

test('Test', () => {
  mod.do_thing();
});

but get

ReferenceError: Thing is not defined

Even removing var thing will cause errors if do_thing has calls to functions defined in other files, as is usually the case in legacy projects.

ReferenceError: foo() is not defined

Any tips? Possible to mock out things using jest.fn or jest.mock similar without heavy refactoring of the app?

How does it get loaded? You could put something on globalThis?

@DanielA.White The file under test is loaded using require. Lemme try global.This and see.

Actually yes, using global.Thing = jest.fn(); solves it! Funny, I thought I tested that already.

Solution using global.Thing:


/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
global.Thing = jest.fn();
const mod = require('thing.js');

test('Test', () => {
  mod.do_thing();
});

